# Reformat ini string

Tags: linux, bash, ini

I have a text file which contain one line.

```
2019-06-19 09:00 Login successfully [ Section 1] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 2] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 3] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 4] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 5] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 6] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN Program Terminated...
```

I have tried awk but it prints only the last section:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i == "Section") beginning=i; if($i== "OPEN") ending=i }; for (j=beginning;j<=ending;j++) printf $j" ";printf "\n"   }'
```

```
Section 6] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN
```

How do I reformat to this pattern?

```
2019-06-19 09:00
[Session 1]
Param1 : xxxx
Param2 : xxxx
Param3 : xxxx
Param4 : xxxx
State  : OPEN

...
...

[Session 6]
Param1 : xxxx
Param2 : xxxx
Param3 : xxxx
Param4 : xxxx
State : OPEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command works in a more general case (for example, if don't have `Param1`, `Param2` but actual identifiers) and matches your expected output more precisely:

```
sed 's/ \(Login successfully\|Program Terminated...\)//g; s/\[ /[/g; s/\(\[\|[Ss]tate\)/\n\1/g; s/\([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]* :\)/\n\1/g'
```

#### How it works:

The command has 4 separate expressions separated by `;`:

1. `s/ \(Login successfully\|Program Terminated...\)//g` - removes unneeded `Login successfully` and `Program Terminated...` with a space before them
2. `s/\[ /[/g` - removes space after `[`
3. `s/\(\[\|[Ss]tate\)/\n\1/g` - adds a newline before `State` or `state`
4. `s/\([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]* :\)/\n\1/g` - adds a newline before "Params", where its name consists of uppercase letter (`[A-Z]`) and then any ASCII letter or digit (`[A-Za-z0-9]`)

#### Example:

```
$ STRING="2019-06-19 09:00 Login successfully [ Section 1] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 2] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 3] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 4] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 5] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 6] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN Program Terminated..."
$ echo $STRING | sed 's/ \(Login successfully\|Program Terminated...\)//g; s/\[ /[/g; s/\(\[\|[Ss]tate\)/\n\1/g; s/\([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]* :\)/\n\1/g'
2019-06-19 09:00
[Section 1]
Param1 : xxxx
Param2 : xxxx
Param3 : xxxx
Param4 : xxxx
State: OPEN
[Section 2]
Param1 : xxxx
Param2 : xxxx
Param3 : xxxx
Param4 : xxxx
State: OPEN
[Section 3]
Param1 : xxxx
Param2 : xxxx
Param3 : xxxx
Param4 : xxxx
State: OPEN
[Section 4]
Param1 : xxxx
Param2 : xxxx
Param3 : xxxx
Param4 : xxxx
State: OPEN
[Section 5]
Param1 : xxxx
Param2 : xxxx
Param3 : xxxx
Param4 : xxxx
State: OPEN
[Section 6]
Param1 : xxxx
Param2 : xxxx
Param3 : xxxx
Param4 : xxxx
State: OPEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[<space>` with `[` and add a newline before `[`, `Param` and `State` strings:

```
$ sed 's/\[ /[/g; s/\(\[\|Param\|State\)/\n\1/g' <<<'2019-06-19 09:00 Login successfully [ Section 1] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 2] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 3] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 4] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 5] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN [ Section 6] Param1 : xxxx Param2 : xxxx Param3 : xxxx Param4 : xxxx State: OPEN Program Terminated...'
2019-06-19 09:00 Login successfully 
[Section 1] 
Param1 : xxxx 
Param2 : xxxx 
Param3 : xxxx 
Param4 : xxxx 
State: OPEN 
[Section 2] 
Param1 : xxxx 
Param2 : xxxx 
Param3 : xxxx 
Param4 : xxxx 
State: OPEN 
[Section 3] 
Param1 : xxxx 
Param2 : xxxx 
Param3 : xxxx 
Param4 : xxxx 
State: OPEN 
[Section 4] 
Param1 : xxxx 
Param2 : xxxx 
Param3 : xxxx 
Param4 : xxxx 
State: OPEN 
[Section 5] 
Param1 : xxxx 
Param2 : xxxx 
Param3 : xxxx 
Param4 : xxxx 
State: OPEN 
[Section 6] 
Param1 : xxxx 
Param2 : xxxx 
Param3 : xxxx 
Param4 : xxxx 
State: OPEN Program Terminated...
```

Comment: How do i if the my Param like this pattern.


2019-06-19 09:00 Login successfully [Section 1] Username : xxxx Host : xxx URL : xxx state : OPEN [Section 2] Username : xxxx Host : xxx URL : xxx state : OPEN Program Terminated...

Comment: @Mr.K Check out my answer, it should work with this pattern.